# Prove that $\sum \hat y_i(y_i-\hat y_i)=0$ for linear regression model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model

Prove that  $\sum \hat y_i(y_i-\hat y_i)=0$ for linear regression model.

Attempt

We have that $\sum \hat y_i(y_i-\hat y_i)=\sum x_i\hat\beta(x_i\beta-x_i\hat\beta)=(X\hat\beta)'(X\beta)-(X\hat\beta)'(X\hat\beta)=\hat\beta'X'X\beta-\hat\beta'X'X\hat\beta= \ ?$

Could someone please help?

Comment: Plug in $\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ to see if you can get the result.

Comment: Hint: look at the first order conditions that define $\hat{\beta}$

Comment: Additionally your second eq is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum \hat y_i(y_i-\hat y_i)=\sum x_i\hat\beta(y_i-x_i\hat\beta)=(X\hat\beta)'Y-(X\hat\beta)'(X\hat\beta)=\hat\beta'X'Y-\hat\beta'X'X\hat\beta= \hat\beta'X'Y-\hat\beta'X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y = \hat\beta'X'Y - \hat\beta'X'Y = 0$

Comment: what do you mean? need more characters?

Comment: "at least 15 characters" to click "Add Comment"